# Searching for files with parenthesis in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

As Google Drive seems to create duplicate files with a " (1)" at the end, without the quotes, when it's not sure how to resolve conflicts, it would seem sensible if you could actually search for filenames containing parenthesis in the Google Drive application.  I have tried most things I can think of and tried searching a few forums, asking ChatGPT and the web in general to no avail... Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but the real problem is that Drive, in the browser, allows duplicate file/folder names — so they don't actually include the "(1)" as far as I can tell.

I got around this by going to the Drive folder locally on my Mac (assuming you installed the desktop client) and searching for `"(1)"` (include the quotation marks) in Finder. Then, after spot checking to make sure the results were truly duplicates, I deleted all the resultant folders.

Voila.